# Make a piece of a mesh the same width

Tags: mesh

How do I get all the spokes at the ends as wide as at the beginning (0.04635 m).[image]

All lines marked with green must remain in place, so only the outermost lines marked with orange must be moved

to the position of the orange lines for all spokes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the *Transform Pivot Point* is set to *Individual Origins* and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> *Extrude Faces*, or simply <kbd>E</kbd>:

[image]

It should work as expected:

[image]

Comment: Okay, I've deleted my answer - you were 5 seconds quicker than me ;)

Comment: hey sorry for that  ;)

Comment: That works moonboots, but... see second photo.

Comment: do you mean that the inner lines need to scale contrary to the outermost? I'm not sure there's any automatic way to do it, could you please show a drawing of before and after (what it is supposed to be at the end)? it will be more clear

Answer (score 3):

Working at World 0, in the XY plane, X across...

- Starting with 1/10th of your cog, deleting unwanted faces:

[image]

- Give the segment a *Mirror* modifier, in X:

[image]

- Add an Empty to the origin, and rotate in Z by 72 degrees
- Give the Mirrored segment an Array modifier.. 'Object Offset', with the Empty as its Axis/Orientation:

[image]

- <kbd>K</kbd> Knife with <kbd>C</kbd> to constrain to vertical, cut the new edge, and ...

[image]

- Delete unwanted face.

[image]

with this result. Apply the modifiers,if you have no further work per-segment,  and maybe <kbd>M</kbd> merge all vertices by distance, to be sure.

[image]

Comment: Can you be a little more clear, I'm a relative beginner with blender ?

Comment: Hi, @Mick.  Sure. Sorry. See Edit.